# What creates black streams in fountain-type fireworks?

Tags: thermodynamics, visible-light, everyday-life

For the New Year celebration of 2014, my nephews set off a series of fountain-type fireworks (as shown below).

[image]

When one looks carefully into the shower of light, one notices that a fair number of "long, black and stringy streams of light" are coming out of the fountain. Note: I do not see any black streams in this picture!

After reading this online article from the [American Chemical Society](http://www.acs.org/content/dam/acsorg/education/resources/highschool/chemmatters/archive/chemmatters-october-2010-fireworks-article.pdf), the colors of light are, of course,  created from electrons jumping orbitals. However, how are these “black streams” created? I assume that somehow visible light is being absorbed to create these "black streams of light".

What mechanism is responsible for this to occur? Are there small bits of matter that are large enough and cooled enough to absorb visible light? I really don’t know. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you highlight or circle one of the black streams?

Comment: @BMS: please note that Jesus has already stated in the second sentence that these "black streams of matter" are not visible in the image provided. However, I can also verify that they do exist since I have also seen them. I always assumed that they were used-up pieces of hot black debris from the fireworks that is leaving a trail of smoke. That makes more sense to me.